# Monoids in single-sorted definition of a category

Tags: category-theory, morphism

In a way of defining a category called as ***single-sorted definition of a category*** which uses only one collection (representing the collection of morphisms) and thus is formulated as an untyped (or 1-sorted) first-order theory, **the basic idea is that an object can be identified with its identity morphism**.

---

**Definition**

A **category** (single-sorted version) is a collection *C*, whose elements are called morphisms, together with two functions *s,t:C→C* and a partial function *∘:C×C→C*, such that:

- *s(s(x))=s(x)=t(s(x))*
- *t(t(x))=t(x)=s(t(x))*

**The elements of their common image (the *x* such that *s(x)=x*, or equivalently *t(x)=x*) are called *identities* or *objects*.**

---

https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/single-sorted+definition+of+a+category

At the same time, the nLab article also mentions:

---

***Specializations***

A monoid is a single-sorted category in which ***s*** is a constant function (hence so is ***t***, and they are equal). This works up to isomorphism of categories, not merely equivalence, so single-sorted categories may seem to be a more direct oidification of monoids than the usual categories.

---

I understood ***s*** and ***t*** are identity morphism *s,t:C→C*, but here it claims they are constant functions, and I feel it does not make sense.

Does this exactly mean, function composition such as

*(C→5)∘(C→C)*??

I am still confused.

In addition, for the mention:

> This works up to isomorphism of categories, not merely equivalence, so single-sorted categories may seem to be a more direct oidification of monoids than the usual categories.

I don't quite understand the meaning.

Can someone who is familiar with **single-sorted definition of a category** explain? Thanks.

Perhaps, this topic is related to a Q&A: [The $2$-category of monoids](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2751722/the-2-category-of-monoids)

Comment: You seem to be confused between identity morphisms and endomorphisms. The identity morphism is an endomorphism. Not every endomorphism is the identity morphism.

Comment: Thanks, but I understand that, and I think that is nothing to do with this topic. Perhaps, you didn't read the question well, this is about identity morphism.

Comment: $s$ and $t$ are *not* the identity morphism $C \to C$ in general. I believe this is what @ZhenLin's comment is saying – if $s$ and $t$ are the identity, then every endomorphism would be the identity morphism.

Comment: @diracdeltafunk  Thanks, so "The elements of their common image (the x such that s(x)=x, or equivalently t(x)=x) are called identities or objects." in Definition in the article https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/single-sorted+definition+of+a+category, are they saying `x` is called identities or objects?

Comment: Correct. If $x$ is a morphism such that $s(x) = x$, then $x$ is called an identity (you might also call $x$ an "identity morphism" or "object", these all mean the same thing).

Comment: @diracdeltafunk Thank you for making things clear! So, the 2 formulas of *s* and *t* is just to define the category needs to be **closed** under the composition operation?

Comment: No, closure under composition is not related to the formulas $s(s(x)) = s(x) = t(s(x)), t(t(x)) = t(x) = s(t(x))$. These formulas just say (by definition) that $s(x)$ and $t(x)$ are always objects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I understood ***s*** and ***t*** are identity morphism *s,t:C→C*

I don't know what you mean by this. The intended interpretation is that $C$ is the collection of all morphisms in a category and $s, t$ send a morphism $f : x \to y$ in the ordinary sense to the identity endomorphism of its source $s(f) = \text{id}_x$ and target $t(f) = \text{id}_y$ respectively.

If we have a monoid $M$, interpreted as a one-object category $BM$ (so there is one object $\bullet$ and it has endomorphisms $M$), then both $s$ and $t$ are necessarily constant, and their constant value is the identity endomorphism $\text{id}_{\bullet}$ of the unique object $\bullet$ of $BM$. Is it clear now?

Comment: Thank you, in fact, I've been thinking about your answer and will reply later. So far the notation *BM* is confusing. What does this stand for? One more thing endomorphism  id∙ what is this dot? Thanks.

Comment: It stands for the one-object category with endomorphisms $M$. The dot is the one object.

Comment: OK, thanks, but I mean, why *B*?

Comment: It's completely irrelevant to this discussion, just my preferred notation, but $B$ means "delooping": https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/delooping